# iphone add data to server and display in a tableView

Tags: objective-c

I have been working on this for a few days now, and getting nowhere. I would appreciate any help on this.

I am creating an app that gets data (something like a list of note) from a server, and display it in a table view.

When user wants to display/refresh the data in the table view, user taps the refresh button. Then, I call my "refreshNote" method which looks like this:(simple version)

```
-(IBAction)refreshNote:(id)sender{
    NSString *getNoteCGI = @"http://....../get-notes.cgi";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:getNoteCGI];
    NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];
}
```

When the connection was successful, I store each retrieved note information in my "notes" array in the AppDelegate file. And the note contains:

```
noteId (auto incremented id)
userId
timestamp
noteText
```

Up to this point, it's working fine. 
But, to add a new note, user taps the "add" button placed in the table view. By tapping the "add" button, the app moves to a view controller which shows text boxes for userId and noteText. When the "send" button in the view controller is tapped, I'm calling the following method:

```
-(IBAction)send:(id)sender{
    NSString *userId = self.userIdTextField.text;
    NSString *note = self.noteTextField.text;
    Note *note = [[Note alloc] init];
    note.userId = userId;
    note.note = note;
    NSString *addCGI = @"http://......../add-note.cgi";
    NSURL *rul = [NSURL URLWithString:addCGI];
    NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];
    addConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:YES];

    if(addConnection){
        AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        [appDelegate.notes addObject:newNote];
    }else{
        return;
    }   
}
```

This kind of successfully adds a new tweet to the table view, but it doesn't show the `noteId` and the `timestamp` correctly because I'm just adding the `userId` and `noteText` to the `notes` array.

So should I just refresh the table view as soon as I add a new note to the server? Is that the only thing I need to do? I'm completely lost and not sure if I'm on the right track or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `noteId` & `timestamp` are added at the server side (with no problem) **AND** If you are successfully retrieving the data from the server by the above code; **Then you should**

1. post data to the server first
2. after successful completion of post request, again, fetch the data from the server
3. after successful get data You should be reloading the table with latest data

So, **YES**, You are thinking it in right direction.

Comment: Great! I wasn't sure if I'm just missing other importance pieces or not. Thank you so much.